# Annotation Processors and modules

Tags: java, module, annotations

The context of this question is annotation processing in recent JDK versions (specifically EclipseLink's metamodel generation processor). The Maven plugins that are used to simplify configuring annotation processors with javac all seem to fail when the package being processed defines `module-info.java` - no modules are found, even though the usual compilation task in the same project works fine. If you delete `module-info.java` annotation processing succeeds.

The recent modifications to the Java AnnotationProcessing API include the addition of an `addModules()` method to `CompilationTask`. I have been trying to see if invoking this in these plugins might resolve the issue, to no avail.

What can be done?